# Coinmarketcap API call with PHP and choose data set with slug

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I tried to do my first API calls which worked finally with help from this great users here in this community. Thanks again. I want to choose *data[1]* or the currency with *symbol*. So i could use a $variable from my CMS. Maybe someone can show me a way how i can change this call to symbol. Here is my API call.

```
$url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";

$headers = [
  'Accepts: application/json',
  'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: ___YOUR_API_KEY_HERE___'
];

$request = "{$url}"; // create the request URL

$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource
// Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $request,            // set the request URL
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,     // set the headers 
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1         // ask for raw response instead of bool
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$json = json_decode($response);
curl_close($curl); // Close request

$price = $json->data[1]->quote->USD->price; echo $price;
```

Comment: What do you mean by symbol? You mean like access the property of quote dynamically? `$json->data[0]->quote->{$variable}->price`

Comment: yes exactly this is my question. to choose the data set by symbol like ETH or BTC.

Comment: You do it with the example I put it.

Comment: can i add there ETH for example? If i only add ETH is do not work.

Comment: You should also include some data samples. Usually you can var dump the json data and see what entries you have there. Maybe ETH isnt listed in it

Comment: Is it listed for sure. You can call it with data 1,2,3.  I only need a way to call the data[1] with symbol which would be ETH.

Comment: Maybe to change the URL and let data at 0. But i can not find a working solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the data block IDs with `array_column()`, then you get the symbol's data block ID with `array_search()`:

```
$data_ids = array_column($json->data, 'symbol');
$symbol_data_id = array_search('ETH', $data_ids);
$price = $json->data[$symbol_data_id]->quote->USD->price;
```

Or as an oneliner:

```
$price = $json->data[array_search('ETH', array_column($json->data, 'symbol'))]->quote->USD->price;
```

---

LATER UPDATE: OK, let me elaborate on this. Step by step:

1. You need a proper URL to acces the API. For this you need the API documentation. Your original question mentioned

`$url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest";`

while for your comment question you need something like

`$url = "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info?symbol=ETH";`

2. A proper URL will give you a JSON response structured according to its purpose. You have this part ironed out, so I'll not insist on this. From your question text:

```
$headers = [
    'Accepts: application/json',
    'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY: 1b58ff56-58b2-4fd0-b184-f9c3dd4ff106',
];

$request = "{$url}"; // create the request URL

$curl = curl_init(); // Get cURL resource
                     // Set cURL options
curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL            => $request, // set the request URL
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => $headers, // set the headers
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,        // ask for raw response instead of bool
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl); // Send the request, save the response
$json     = json_decode($response);
curl_close($curl); // Close request
```

3. Then you have to decide how to use the response. For me, the fastest way is to look at its structure (`var_dump($json)` or `print_r($json)`). Which will give something like this (the original question):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2021-11-06T18:37:59.447Z
            [error_code] => 0
            [error_message] => 
            [elapsed] => 22
            [credit_count] => 1
            [notice] => 
            [total_count] => 7060
        )

    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Bitcoin

                    [...]
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1027
                    [name] => Ethereum
                    [symbol] => ETH
                    [slug] => ethereum

                    [...]

                    [quote] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [USD] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [price] => 4445.0743486785
                                    [volume_24h] => 14137477206.072
                                    [volume_change_24h] => -9.6622
                                    [percent_change_1h] => 0.2898806
                                    [percent_change_24h] => -1.29677209
                                    [percent_change_7d] => 3.13286959
                                    [percent_change_30d] => 23.49191199
                                    [percent_change_60d] => 28.79913805
                                    [percent_change_90d] => 48.37310902
                                    [market_cap] => 525560956659.07
                                    [market_cap_dominance] => 19.5198
                                    [fully_diluted_market_cap] => 525560956659.07
                                    [last_updated] => 2021-11-06T18:37:03.000Z
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => stdClass Object [...]
```

or this (the question in the comment):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => stdClass Object
        (
            [timestamp] => 2021-11-06T18:03:05.201Z
            [error_code] => 0
            [error_message] => 
            [elapsed] => 12
            [credit_count] => 1
            [notice] => 
        )

    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ETH] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1027
                    [name] => Ethereum
                    [symbol] => ETH
                    [category] => coin
                    [description] => Ethereum (ETH) is a cryptocurrency . Users are able to generate ETH through the process of mining. Ethereum has a current supply of 118,233,336.749. The last known price of Ethereum is 4,424.33123326 USD and is down -1.39 over the last 24 hours. It is currently trading on 4537 active market(s) with $14,138,162,060.93 traded over the last 24 hours. More information can be found at https://www.ethereum.org/.

                    [...]

                    [platform] => 
                    [date_added] => 2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z
                    [twitter_username] => ethereum
                    [is_hidden] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

So `data` is a property of the $json object.

In the first case, `data` is an array and its structure suggests using array functions to retrieve specific data.

In the second case, `data` and `ETH` are objects, while description is a property of ETH. Which allows me to get the description using object syntax

```
$description = $json->data->ETH->description;
```

Comment: And on https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/info should be like this? Or works this on another way? This will be empty.

$logourl = $json->data[array_search('ETH', array_column($json->data, 'symbol'))]->logo;

Comment: Please keep in mind that array search may return false as well, if no match.

Comment: @paulmagmusik - it depends on the data structure. What I did was to `var_dump($json)` and look at the data type. The one in your first question was an array. This one (`.../info/`) sends an object and works like `$description = $json->data->$symbol->description;`
@mujnoi-gyula-tamas - absolutely. I left out any exception handling for the sake of clarity.

Comment: can you maybe post me a oneliner for description. i do not find the right way. from description i can copy it to the others.

Comment: @paulmagmusik - I edited my answer to add more explaining. I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, very good explanation. I understand now much more how it works. I really appreciate this. One last question. How i handle this aray in the first case to get the logo or website? This is really my last question. Do not want to take any more of your time :-)

Comment: Or data aray was the first thing we did on top? $price = $json->data[array_search('ETH', array_column($json->data, 'symbol'))]->website; This is not working here.

Comment: $website = $json->data->ETH->urls->website; answers "Array".

Comment: $price = $json->data[array_search('ETH', array_column($json->data, 'symbol'))]->urls->website; with removed ETH and symbol in the url is also not working.

Comment: $website = $json->data array('urls' => 'website');
print json_encode($website);

Comment: Maybe a step closer?

Comment: print_r($json['data']['ETH']['tags']); .. but still an error.